# Why does microwaved water kill plants?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, water, microwaves

I've read tons of articles about microwaved water klling plants and the most of them said it was a myth. So I decided to do this experiment myself on cress plants. I repeated the experiment three times, displaying them to two kinds of stress - dark or stopping watering them. In all three experiments, the microwaved samples died first.

Does anybody know what could microwave possibly do to the water, causing the plants to die?

Comment: Related: [Does microwaved water kill plants?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17930/does-microwaved-water-kill-plants)

Answer (score 5):

If you allowed the water to cool to room temperature you should be alright.

Snopes.com has done some research on this claim, and you can read their report here: http://www.snopes.com/science/microwave/plants.asp

They conducted a blind-study with boiled on a gas stove, boiled in a microwave, and the third was not boiled at all.  All of the water came from the same source, and it was all allowed to cool to room temperature prior to being used to water the three sets of plants.

So you may wish to conduct your experiment in a more controlled fashion, with more plants.